# CSS - Changing the current active state to hover state in this example

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I have some pure CSS navigation I'm working on and I'm trying to get what is currently the "active" state to the hover state. I didn't write the original code *entirely* myself, and it's been somewhat of a time-consuming process reverse-engineering it (the original code was public domain).

[image]

I would like it such that the current "active" state (i.e. menu2) is *also* the hover state, instead of merely changing the background color to be a bit darker.

[You can view a demo here.](http://stoicfury.com/)

You can [download the source here](http://stoicfury.com/source.zip) or view the source from demo above.

<sub>p.s. I considered posting this on webmasters/programmers/code review but it didn't seem quite as appropriate as here, since this isn't asking for a review of my code per se, is a specific rather than a general web question, and is not about programming principles... If I am incorrect, feel free to migrate. :)</sub>

Comment: To clarify, do you want the active to show a hover state on hover, or do you want it to show similar attributes to the hover state all the time (no matter if it's hovered or not)?

Comment: online demo for your editing pleasure: http://jsfiddle.net/uVNEz/

Comment: @JosephMarikle - I know this question is somewhat old but I noticed on this menu that you helped me fix, when you hover over the last option in the dropdown (e.g., menu1 > 'teach your children') and then move *just* past it, your mouse will exist the <a> area causing the background color to return to white but the text color stays white as well. I've looked over the code for a few hours but can't seem to figure out what line is causing it... >.<

Comment: @stoicfury Hello again, stoicfury.  Unfortunately it's 2:07 AM and my thought process is fuzzy, but I did manage to modify a few of the rules to achieve the desired result.  I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SXChF/2/ but as far as what I did, I simply added `color` attributes to existing rules that seemed to be missing them.  Let me know if I need to explain further and I'll do so (at a more decent hour of the day).

Comment: Awesome, I owe you once again! Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're after correct?

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SXChF/show)

#### [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/SXChF/)

Mimic the active state to be triggered by the hover state

the key was this css:

```
#hNav>ul>li:hover {height:52px;margin:0;padding:0}
#hNav>ul>li:hover>span.o1{background:transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/ax6LZ.png') left top no-repeat;display:block;height:52px}
#hNav>ul>li:hover>span a{background:transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/zapF1.png') right top no-repeat;color:#000;padding:22px 0 0}
```

<sub>of course those are the demo urls... replace as needed.</sub>

Comment: The only thing I added was `#hNav>ul>li>ul>li {position:relative;left:-1px}` under your code, to shift the menu over so it looks more like it is one piece! works just the way I want it now, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but if you're trying to display a particular style for Hover over an Active element, you can achieve it by chaining the CSS pseudo elements together, ie:

As well as `a:hover { background:#EEE }` you can have `a:active:hover { background:#EEE }` which will only apply to Active Elements on a Hover Event.